# Laravel 5.2 change database column name reference

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello i'm trying to change how to access to a database column name without change the name, for example, my column name is `resourceType` but I want to call it name and also I want the response json appears `name` instead `resourceType`. Looking around internet found I should use `protected $maps = ['oldName' => 'newName'];` but doesn't work. I want to change `resourceType` because I think doesn't look good the table name should be equal than a column   `resourceType->resourceType`

This is my model

```
<?php

namespace Knotion;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Mappable, Mutable;

class CTL_ResourceType extends Model  {
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $table = "CTL_ResourceType";
  protected $primaryKey = "idResourceType";

  public $incrementing = false;
  public static $snakeAttributes = false;

  protected $hidden = ['idCountry', 'idCompany', 'initials', 'thumbnail', 'icon', 'status', 'createTime', 'updateTime'];
  protected $fillable = ['name'];

protected $maps = ['resourceType' => 'name'];
protected $appends = ['name'];

  public function resource()  {
    return $this->hasMany('Knotion\CTL_Resource', 'idResource' );
  }
  public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_Country', 'idCountry', 'idCountry');
  }
  public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Knotion\CTL_Company', 'idCompany', 'idCompany');
  }


}
```

and this is the response JSON I'm receiving. As you see `resourceType` stills there instead `name`

```
{
  "total": 16,
  "per_page": 15,
  "current_page": 1,
  "last_page": 2,
  "next_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/krb/api/resources?page=2",
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "from": 1,
  "to": 15,
  "data": [
    {
      "idResource": "4e8f1ece-f666-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
      "productionKey": "238493ujjsl",
      "title": "ElTitle16",
      "description": "ElDescription16",
      "minimumAge": "4",
      "maximumAge": "15",
      "fileName": "ElFileName16",
      "extension": ".png",
      "URL": "ElURL16",
      "createTime": "2016-03-30 04:58:16",
      "creatorUser": {
        "idUser": "85cf125c-f5ff-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
        "name": "Roberto"
      },
      "creationCountry": {
        "idCountry": "f03a75a0-f5ff-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
        "country": "Estados Unidos"
      },
      "resourceType": {
        "idResourceType": "5c902028-f601-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
        "resourceType": "TípodeRecurso3"
      },
      "tags": [
        {
          "idTag": "40c6a114-f520-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
          "name": "ElTag1"
        }
      ],
      "quickTags": [
        {
          "idQuickTag": "679bc8f0-f520-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
          "name": "ElQuickTag4"
        }
      ],
      "relatedTo": [
        {
          "idRelatedTo": "7beddc6c-f520-11e5-8137-0f7932903a75",
          "name": "ElRelatedTo3"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: How come you don't just migrate:refresh in artisan?

Comment: They gave me already a designed database, only SQL.

Comment: Ah I see, that kinda sucks

Comment: Yeah, I have some experience with Laravel but only when I use migrations. I've been having a lot of troubles with this project because of that but i'm learning a lot thanks to internet and people who share knowledge. :)

Comment: Yeah can't say I've ever not had the freedom to make database amendments using artisan. Also seen some cases of huge data loss though, so can kind of see why some of these workarounds are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't heard of the `$maps` property or `Mappable` before, so I did a quick search. It looks like they (as well as `Mutable`) are part of the [jarektkaczyk/eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) package.

In this case, both `Mappable` and `Mutable` are traits that are supposed to be added to the class. Additionally, in order for them to work properly, you need to add in the `Eloquence` trait, as well.

Your `use` statements at the top of your file need to be changed to properly address the class names in the correct namespace, and then you need to add the traits to your class:

```
<?php
namespace Knotion;

// import the class names
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mutable;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CTL_ResourceType extends Model  {

    // add the traits to the class
    use Eloquence, Mappable, Mutable;

    // code...
}
```

### Edit

If you wanted to do this without the package, you need to do three things:

1. You need to add `resourceType` to your `$hidden` array, so that it won't show up in your `toArray()`/`toJson()` results.

   ```
   protected $hidden = ['idCountry', 'idCompany', 'initials', 'thumbnail', 'icon', 'status', 'createTime', 'updateTime', 'resourceType'];
   ```
2. You need to create a `getNameAttribute()` [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), which will be called whenever you attempt to access the `name` attribute.

   ```
   public function getNameAttribute() {
       return $this->resourceType;
   }
   ```
3. You need to add `name` to your `$appends` array, so that it will be included in your `toArray()`/`toJson()` results.

   ```
   protected $appends = ['name'];
   ```

Optionally, if that feels like too much work, you could always just override the `toArray()` method (called by `toJson()`) to force your naming convention, as well:

```
public function toArray() {
    // call parent method to get initial array results
    $array = parent::toArray();

    // set the new key with data
    $array['name'] = $array['resourceType'];

    // unset the old key
    unset($array['resourceType']);

    // return the array
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Ive heard about that solution in morning but I wanted to see if there's another solution without package but it seems no. I appreciate your help again. You deserve a place in heaven, just aside Charles Babbage, or anyone you want. :P  Thank you, i'm so grateful with you for your help and time.

Comment: @CanKerDiAlike Not a problem at all. I didn't know you were trying to avoid the package, so I have updated my answer with some options for you, with explanation. Hope it helps.